# Issue with 2D arrays and for loop

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array

im very new to C++ programming and i have an issue with 2D array and for loop.. i was looking for solution all over program that i made recently, but everything else works good. Except this for loop.

This is just a small part of program, but seems problem is over this code. This program is basically a test. There is like 5 questions with 3 answer options and user should enter 1, 2, 3 (int values, function that is responsible for getting these values to atsakymai[] array is working properly tho). JDM, USDM, EUDM arrays should keep points for right answer (they are set to 0 at start). atsakymoVerte array keeps answers order from which points depends on. For ex. 1 - +1 point to JDM; 2 - 1+ to USDM; 3 - 1+ to EUDM.

**This program seems to work properly until for loop reaches y = 4.** But after that it gives bad values... first 3 times loop works good and increments right variables(variables from JDM, USDM or EUDM arrays) by one. Everything works good until this 4th time in the loop... i have no idea what i should change to get it working right. I was sitting beside this problem for a few hours, but yeah... no solution. I hope you guys will understand what is my problem. Thanks.

```
int *JDM = new int[6]();
int *USDM = new int[6]();
int *EUDM = new int[6]();

int atsakymoVerte[6][4] = {
{0,0,0,0},
{0,2,1,3},
{0,2,1,3},
{0,1,2,3},
{0,3,1,2},
{0,3,1,2}
};

for (int y = 1 ; y < 6; y++) {
        for (int x = 1; x < 4; x++) {
           if (atsakymai[y] == atsakymoVerte[y][x]) {
           switch (x) {
                case 1: JDM[y]++;
                    break;
                case 2: USDM[y]++;
                    break;
                case 3: EUDM[y]++;
                    break;
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `atsakymai` declared as?

Comment: @Erikas
Index start at 0, remember that, you are starting x and y at 1.

Comment: Use `std::vector` instead..

Comment: Quit faking 1-based arrays.  In C++, arrays start at 0, not 1.  If I had a dollar for every time I have seen mistakes made due to faking 1-based arrays, I would be a rich man.

Comment: also, when you fix 0 based for loop, the switch statement should become 0,1,2  not 1,2,3

Comment: "user should enter 1, 2, 3", remember, the user entries are typically letters, so they may enter '1', '2', '3', and they remain letters until you convert them to integers.  (i.e. (argv[1][0] - '0') generates the int from the letter.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know about c++ - though many other languages have 0-index arrays. This means that 0 is the first element.

so instead of

```
for (int y = 1 ; y < 6; y++)
        for (int x = 1; x < 4; x++)
```

It should really  be

```
for (int y = 0 ; y < 6; y++)
        for (int x = 0; x < 4; x++)
```

By using the loop you have at the moment, the first pass has `y` equal to `1` - this would be `atsakymai[1]` - which is actually the 2nd element in the `atsakymai` array, not the first.

If you're not careful, you can also end up trying to reference an index that doesn't exist.

Comment: `y < 6` - you still want to access 6th element (with index 5)

Comment: That will go all the way up to the 5th element - as soon as y == 6 it is no longer less than 6 so the loop exits.

Comment: No, your loop will stop when `y == 5` so it will *not* access the last element.

Comment: what bialpio meant is that you're right that it starts at 0, but you have 6 elements to access, so from y = 0 to y < 6, not 5

Comment: @Darren As biapio states, it should be y < 6. So y goes 0,1,2,3,4,5 and then exits instead of 0,1,2,3,4. This is your code, it accesses the second last element but not the last, see 0-4 https://ideone.com/FBz7vw

Comment: @lmgonzalves, why did you reject the proposed edit, which corrects 5 to 6, and 3 to 4. And why did you select *"This edit defaces the post in order to promote a product or service, or is deliberately destructive."*?

Comment: sorry - yes, accidentally changed a little too much :)

Comment: also, switch statement should be 0,1,2  not 1,2,3

Answer (score 1):

I think you are actually calculating loop by n-2 , change you for loops to

```
for (int y = 0 ; y < 6; y++) 
        for (int x = 0; x < 4; x++)
```

and where is this `atsakymai[y]` declared  you must define it to compare your array otherwise you continuously getting error

You are faking a 1-based array, you should not do that. This causes many problems and wastes memory. Why make useless elements, what if you have a "2d" array of 1000 by 1000, you would be wasting 2000 elements.

I would have the following

```
// remove useless elements
int *JDM = new int[5]();
int *USDM = new int[5]();
int *EUDM = new int[5]();

int atsakymoVerte[5][3] = {
{2,1,3},
{2,1,3},
{1,2,3},
{3,1,2},
{3,1,2}
};

for (int y = 0 ; y < 5; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
           // WARNING: Make sure to remove useless elements
           if (atsakymai[y] == atsakymoVerte[y][x]) { // in atsakymai and re-write previous indexes
           switch (x) {
                case 1: JDM[y]++;
                    break;
                case 2: USDM[y]++;
                    break;
                case 3: EUDM[y]++;
                    break;
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: also, switch statement should be 0,1,2  not 1,2,3

Comment: Aight, i managed to get rid of faked 1-based arrays, but problem is still there - after for loop reaches y = 3 it increments wrong array on switch. I have tried to do it with if/elseif, but it didnt worked at all, same problem.

Comment: did you switch your variable in switch statement ?